# Does a Hazelcast cache read have the potential to block a write to the same cache

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We are using a Hazelcast cache within our application.

We are looking at creating a read-only reporting system to display data from items within the cache.

Some of the cached items are quite large.  We are concerned that a read from a new reporting app, of some of these large items, might **block** a write from occurring in one of our existing apps.

Looking at the documentation for Hazelcast's [IMap](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html), I can't see any mention of reads blocking writes.

I *have* read that a cache-miss might cause data to be loaded across to the cache we are accessing.  I think we are fine with that (as long as it doesn't cause write-locks)

Any advice on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, for a default configured IMap the answer is yes but it's unlikely it will cause a problem.  Every operation on a particular key is serviced by the same "partition thread" so any two operations on the same key will be serialized *for a small portion of the entire operation*. See: [here](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.2/manual/html-single/index.html#threading-model). The partition thread will only do the local map operations on the member.  The I/O will be handed off to another thread.  Note that the I/O is the part of the operation that will vary by object size.  So overall, the operations run concurrently but there will be a brief point of synchronization for operations on the same key.  My suggestion would be to perform a high concurrency test.  In practice, I've never seen this be a problem.

If needed, there are a couple of options for allowing completely concurrent reads and writes.  The first would be to enable [read from backups](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.2/manual/html-single/index.html#enabling-backup-reads) and the second would be to enable [near cache](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.2/manual/html-single/index.html#near-cache) on the reporting system clients. Of course in both cases, an additional copy is involved so the "get" may return a value that is behind the current state.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed response.